# How make button which open random page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my first post, so sorry for errors. I have a problem I can't make a button which open radom page in my apk. The project is connected with Coronavirus.

Comment: Can you drop the code?

Comment: what do you mean by page ? website ?

Comment: page for my is next screen

Comment: probably the code is not help us

Comment: I don't get you...

Comment: Boro, there is not enough information in your post for people to be able to help you. You need to:

(1) Show your current code that is not working.
(2) Describe your problem.

And maybe detail how this is connected to COVID-19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use `RouteGenerator` and list with needed random pages for this task.

**main.dart:**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Random pages',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: 'start_page',
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

**route_generator.dart:**

```
class RouteGenerator {

  static List<String> myRandomPages = [
    'first_page',
    'second_page'
  ];

  static String getRandomNameOfRoute(){
    return myRandomPages[Random().nextInt(myRandomPages.length)];
  }

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {

      case 'start_page':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => StartPage());

      case 'first_page':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FirstPage()); // FirstPage - is just a Widget with your content

      case 'second_page':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SecondPage());// Also custom Widget

      //... other random or not pages

    }
  }

}
```

**start_page.dart:**

```
class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Start page'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Go to random page'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteGenerator.getRandomNameOfRoute()),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```