# how to get listview button to go to random route onTap

Tags: flutter, listview, random

I am trying to use solution from here
[How make button which open random page in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904241/how-make-button-which-open-random-page-in-flutter)
but instead of RaisedButton, do it with my Listview buttons.

Here's what I have so far after I added the RandomRouteGenerator from the other StackOverflow:

```
ListView(
      children: const <Widget>[
        Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Text(''),
            title: Text('Chicken'),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                RouteGenerator.getRandomNameOfRoute());
            },
          ),
        ),

//... more Cards that would become other listview items
```

Here's the errors:

```
Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:163:28: Error: Not a constant expression.
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                           ^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:163:25: Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression.
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                        ^^
lib/main.dart:164:32: Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression.
                RouteGenerator.getRandomNameOfRoute());
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:163:37: Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression.
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:162:20: Error: Not a constant expression.
            onTap: () {
                   ^^
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Uni , I am very new at this so I apologize for not recognizing some of the terms. So are you saying that I cannot go to a random route with Listview buttons?

Comment: If you really want to implement what you're trying to do, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766770/how-to-navigate-to-next-page-in-dynamic-list-view-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can remove keyword `const` of `children: const <Widget>[` 
code snippet

```
child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
            Card(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Random pages',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: 'start_page',
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    );
  }
}

class RouteGenerator {
  static List<String> myRandomPages = ['first_page', 'second_page'];

  static String getRandomNameOfRoute() {
    return myRandomPages[Random().nextInt(myRandomPages.length)];
  }

  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case 'start_page':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => StartPage());

      case 'first_page':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>
                FirstPage()); // FirstPage - is just a Widget with your content

      case 'second_page':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => SecondPage()); // Also custom Widget

      //... other random or not pages

    }
  }
}

class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Start page'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(''),
                    title: Text('Chicken'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushNamed(RouteGenerator.getRandomNameOfRoute());
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
            Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Go to random page'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context)
                    .pushNamed(RouteGenerator.getRandomNameOfRoute()),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("First Page");
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("Second Page");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for including what I did wrong, the full code, and what the final product will look like. This has been very educational for me. If you have time, could you explain why keeping "const" in the ListView gave me such troubles?

Comment: you can reference this https://medium.com/@jelenaaa.lecic/what-are-const-objects-in-dart-fd65cf5b0afd

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `const` before the  on the ListView children.